# maximum safe CPU utilization for embedded system

Tags: embedded

What is the safe maximum CPU utilization time for embedded system for critical applications. We are measuring performance with top. Is 50 - 75% is safe?

Comment: I would say yes... Provided all tasks are executed at their scheduled frequency.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense without any specific system in mind, so please edit and narrow it down. 100% CPU utilization is the normal case for critical applications that run single core MCU. Typically you don't allow power-saving sleep modes in such applications unless truly needed, since that adds extra complexity and could expose hardware peripheral sleep mode bugs in the silicon (somewhat common).

Comment: You thinking about CPU utilization and mentioning `top` hints to embedded Linux - That's not considered a "real embedded system" by some people. Agree with Lundin that a typical system running on bare metal or thin RTOS layer will always have 100% utilization, because there's always *something* the CPU must be busy with (even if it's only an idle loop).

Comment: There should be no 100% CPU usage, considering the fact, that there might be an Idle-Task. This is executed, when no other tasks and ISRs are running. But in the end, CPU usage is one measure, but you should not forget the Task & ISR Latencies, If you have cyclic tasks, that also means, they can not run the full time of their cycle period. e.g. a Task with 10ms cycle, running 9ms leaves 1ms for other tasks / ISRs, before this task is scheduled again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real-Time embedded systems are designed to meet Real-Time constraints, for example:

- Voltage acquisition and processing every 500 us (lets say sensor monitoring).
- Audio buffer processing every 5.8 ms (4ms processing).
- Serial Command Acknowledgement within 3ms.

Thanks to Real-Time Operating System (RTOS), which are "preemptive" (the scheduler can suspend a task to execute one with a higher priority), you can meet those constraints even at 100% CPU usage: The CPU will execute the high priority task then resume to whatever it was doing.

But this does not mean you will meet the constraint no matter what, few tips:

- High priority Tasks execution must be as short as possible (by calculating Execution Time/Occurence you can have an estimation of CPU usage).
- If estimated CPU usage is too high, look for code optimization,  hardware equivalent (hardware CRC, DMA, ...), or second micro-processor.
- Stress test your device and measure if your real-time constraints are met.

For the previous example:

- Audio processing should be the lowest priority
- Serial Acknowledgement/Voltage Acquisition the highest
- Stress test can be done by issuing Serial Commands and checking for missed audio buffers, missed analog voltage events and so on. You can also vary CPU clock frequency: your device might meet constraints at much lower clock frequencies, reducing power consumption.

**To answer you question**, 50-75 and even 100% CPU usage is safe as long as you meet real-time constraints, but bear in mind that if you want to add functionality later on, you will not have much room for that at 98% CPU usage.

Comment: Some caution over _"High priority Tasks execution must be as short as possible"_ perhaps.  It is right but for the possibly for the wrong reason or open to misunderstanding.  According to _[rate monotonic scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate-monotonic_scheduling) the execution time determines the optimum priority.  It is not uncommon for the unwary to confuse "high-priority" with "important", but schedulability is about getting _all_ things done on-time, not important things first, at the risk of missing subjectively less "important" deadlines..

Answer (score 1):

In [rate monotonic scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate-monotonic_scheduling) mathematical analysis determines that real-time tasks (that is tasks with specific real-time deadlines) are schedulable when the utilisation is below about 70% (and priorities are appropriately assigned). If you have accurate statistics for all tasks and they are deterministic this can be as high as 85% and still guarantee schedulability.

Note however that the utilisation applies only to tasks with hard-real-time deadlines.  Background tasks may utilise the remaining CPU time all the time without missing deadlines.

Assuming by "CPU utilization" you are referring to time spent executing code other than an idle loop, in a system with a preemptive priority based scheduler, then ... it depends.

First of all there is a measurement problem; if your utilisation sampling period is sufficiently short, it will often switch between 100% and zero, whereas if it were very long you'd get a good average, but would not know if utilisation was high for long-enough to starve a lower priority task than that running to the extent that it might miss its deadlines.  It is kind of the wrong question, because any practical utilisation sampling rate will typically be much longer then the shortest deadline, so is at best a qualitative rather then quantitative measure.  It does not tell you much that is useful in critical cases.

Secondly there is teh issue of what you are measuring.  While it is common for an RTOS to have a means to measure CPU utilisation, it is measuring utilisation by all tasks including those that have no deadlines.

If the utilisation becomes 100% in the lowest priority task for example, there is no harm to schedulabilty - the low priority task is in this sense no different from the idle loop.  It may have consequences for power consumption in systems that normally enter a low-power mode in the idle loop.

It a higher priority task takes 100% CPU utilisation such that a deadline for a lower priority task is missed, then your system will fail (in the sense that deadlines will be missed - the consequences are application specific).

Simply measuring CPU utilisation is insufficient, but if your CPU is at 100% utilisation and that utilisation is not simply some background task in the lowest priority thread, it is probably not schedulable- there will be stuff not getting done.  The consequences are of course application dependent.

Whilst having a low priority background thread consume 100% CPU may do no harm, it does render the ability to measure CPU utilisation entirely useless. If the task is preemted and for some reason the higher priority task take 100%, you may have no way of detecting the issue and the background task (and any tasks lower then the preempting task) will not get done.  It is better therefore to ensure that you have some idle time so that you can detect abnormal scheduling behaviour (if you have no other means to do so).

One common solution to the non-yielding background task problem is to perform such tasks in the idle loop.  Many RTOS allow you to insert idle-loop hooks to do this.  The background task is then preemptable but not included in the utilisation measurement.  In that case of course you cannot then have a low-priority task that does not yield, because your idle-loop does stuff.

When assigning priorities, the task with the shortest execution time should have the highest priority.  Moreover the execution time should be more deterministic in higher priority tasks - that is if it takes 100us to run it should within some reasonable bounds always take that long.  If some processing might be variable such that it takes say 100us most of the time and must occasionally do something that requires say 100ms; then the 100ms process should be passed off to some lower priority task (or the priority of the task temporarily lowered, but that pattern may be hard to manage and predict, and may cause subsequent deadlines or events to be missed).

So if you are a bit vague about your task periods and deadlines, a good rule of thumb is to keep it below 70%, but not to include non-real-time background tasks in the measurement.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Clifford!)